# Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="data"> 
    <application
        android:label="data"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
```

Exception: [!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

I saw the same name package, label but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

- error message indicates Gradle project being used in your Android manifest file is not supported, this could be happening due to various reasons such as `outdated dependencies or incompatible configurations`.
- Creating a new Flutter project and moving your code, assets, and configuration files to the new project can help resolve this issue. By starting with a fresh project, you ensure that you have the latest dependencies and configurations, which are more likely to be compatible with your current setup.
- run this command `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` After creating the new project, you can move your `Dart code`, `assets`, and `pubspec.yaml` file to the `new project`.